# Getting session ID with $session->getId() returns an empty result in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, shopping-cart, sessionid, string

I want to getting session ID to store it in the database (because I store shopping carts in my database). Thereby, I want to get session ID, with this method:

```
$session = $this->get('session');
$carts->setSessionId($session->getId());
```

But this method returns an empty result. It's really weird because if I send this ID in my view with, for exemple:

```
'session' => $session->getId(),
```

It works... It's really strangely ; have I make an error in my code?

getSessionId() and setSessionId() functions:

```
/**
 * Set sessionId
 *
 * @param string $sessionId
 * @return Carts
 */
public function setSessionId($sessionId)
{
    $this->sessionId = $sessionId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get sessionId
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSessionId()
{
    return $this->sessionId;
}
```

Thank you per advance!

Comment: what is $carts in your example ? a collection, a single object?

Comment: $carts is an entity (to store carts in database)

Comment: what do you mean this method returns an empty result? after calling $carts->setSessionId($sesson->getId()) ... $carts->getSessionId() does not return the id ? if yes please provide a gist /pastebin with those 2 methods or post them here

Comment: after calling $carts->setSessionId($sesson->getId()), $carts->getSessionId() no return ID (I did $a = $carts->getSessionId() and I sent this variable to my view)

Comment: then please put your getSessionId and setSessionId methods into the question so we can inspect them.

Comment: it's done, but please confirm that I've put is what you've asked (I'm still pretty novice on Symfony2)

Comment: Yes that's what i wanted to see but i don't see anything wrong here ...do you have a protected/private property sessionId in your entity ? By the way .. method arguments are under_score by convention in symfony2

Comment: It's not me but the doctrine generator who not use the under_score convention. :-°
$sessionId is private, so I just tried to put it in protected and public but neither works.

Comment: what is the return value of $session->isStarted() in your controller?

Comment: So I added $session->start(); and no it works! Really thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make sure your session has been **started** otherwise *Session::getId()* returns am **empty string** ('').
See [Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php#L164)

```
$session = $this->get('session');
$session->start();
$carts->setSessionId( $session->getId() );
```

Comment: Really thank you, although I'm disgusted to have had a so small error